# Unix command to find all files

Tags: unix, terminal, command

I need a unix command to list all files that contains 'foo' in their name ?
We have two commands that do that : grep command and find command !!
what's the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` command by itself suffices (unless you want to include files in directories whose name includes "foo"):

```
find / -type f -name '*foo*'
```

That checks the *leaf* name (last part) of the pathnames.  If you piped the result of `find` through `grep` in a similar way:

```
find / -type f | grep foo
```

it would match those files, as well as all files (and directories) inside directories whose name includes "foo".

To filter the list in a more interesting way, you can use `grep`, which supports regular expressions and other features.  For example, you could do

```
find / -type f | grep -i foo
```

to match "foo" ignoring case.

But if you want to look at the *contents* of files, that is grep-specific:

```
find / -type f -exec grep foo {} +
```

Further reading:

- [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)
- [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)

Comment: nice summary & explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use find to list all files on the system.

Pair that up with grep to search for a specific file name.

like this:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -i -r "*foo*" {}
```